# How to model a process where dependent variable is duration of stay (in integers) at present dwelling?

Tags: modeling, model

I would like to apologize first if my question is not appropriate for the StackExchange. 
I have data on households' expenditure, socio-economic characteristics, features of dwellings they are living at and a variable which reports duration of stay at current dwelling in integers (0 and more than 0). 
I thought of Count data models, but it not a variable which is a count of a process in given duration. 
The survival analysis also doesn't seem to be applicable, though I do not have convincing argument about whether it is right approach or not. But it seems that my dependent variable is like a distance from an event (change of dwelling if there is previous dwelling) rather than time to event, though it can be thought that all households are heading to next change of dwelling.

The question that I am trying to answer is: what determines/affects the duration of stay of a household at a rented dwelling they are currently residing? My dataset is a cross-section of households from a metropolitan region in India. Apart from socio-economic characteristics like social group, education and expenditure (not income), information on various dwelling characteristics is available.

My dependent variable is 'duration of stay at present dwelling', measured in years, starting with 0 for the household who have moved to present dwelling during last 365 days. For independent variables, I have thought of following variables: 
1. Household size 
2. Monthly Expenditure (proxy for income)
3. Housing type: independent house/dwelling in multi-family building (called 'flat' in India/slum dwellings/non-slum tenement under rent control (dichotomous variable for each of the 3 categories of 4 mentioned)
4. Location of the dwelling (measured by the 'location index')
5. Rent 
6. Floor area of the housing 
7. Quality of the housing

There is clear incidence of omitted variables, most notably information on neighbourhood composition and availability of schools, hospitals in the vicinity.

Comment: Welcome! If I understand you correctly, you are asking which model is recommended for a specific research question. IMO this is a fine question for Crossvalidated. It would help if you add some information. What is the exact question you are trying to answer? Could you show a sample of what your data looks like? Please include what  the intended role of the variables in your data is (dependent/outcome, independent/predictor, side information, data selection, etc.)? This would help readers understand and answer your question. And take a look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

A simpler answer may be possible if more clear information is available on your question.

A simple case if for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: I have edited my question to include what question I am trying to answer by the model.